# Is there any difference between iterator methods returning IEnumerable<T> and IEnumerator<T>?

Tags: c#, iterator

Consider two iterator methods with the same bodies:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> It1() { 
    ...
}

public static IEnumerator<int> It2() { 
    ...
}
```

Is there any circumstance where calling `It2` is different from calling `It1.GetEnumerator()`?

Is there ever a good reason to define an iterator as `IEnumerator<T>` over `IEnumerable<T>`? The only one I can think of is when you are implementing `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()`.

EDIT: By iterator methods I mean methods using `yield return` and `yield break` constructs.

Comment: Strictly speaking implementations of methods cannot be same.

Comment: Of course it can. 

public static IEnumerable<int> It1() { 
yield return 1;
}

public static IEnumerator<int> It2() { 
yield return 1;
}

Comment: Now, what the compiler converts them into obviously differs; one gets converted into an anonymous class implementing IEnumerator<T>, and the other into two anonymous classes implementing IEnumerable<T> and IEnumerator<T>. Is there a case when the two IEnumerators are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this if you wanted to take charge of writing the `IEnumerable<T>` wrapper class.

Let's say that you have a class that you want to do enumeration on, infinitely:

```
public class EveryDateInTheFuture : IEnumerable<DateTime>
{
    public EveryDateInTheFuture() { this.StartDate = DateTime.Today; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<DateTime> GetEnumerator()
    {
         while (true)
         {
             yield return date;
             date = date.AddDays(1);
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

As noted, you can't `foreach` over an `IEnumerator<T>`.  Because of that, it makes it difficult to integrate into places in code where you want to iterate over what you are returning.

Also, the imporance here is that `IEnumerable<T>` is meant to be a factory, so that you can produce implementations of `IEnumerator<T>` that aren't directly tied to the implementation of the collection of `T`.

Even more important now is the fact that all the extension methods for LINQ work off `IEnumerable<T>`, so you will want to make your enumerations as easy to work with as possible by returning that.

Comment: Yes, that's all good reasons to prefer IEnumerable<T> over IEnumerator<T>. That's why I asked about the opposite direction.